# Full-screen post-processing and texture size

Tags: opengl-es2, post-processing

I am newbie writing a post-processing code for mobile devices, and asking some trivial, conventional solution for a specific problem.

AFAIK, post-processing in OpenGL is trivially done with FBO bound to a texture. Anyway, target screen size is usually not square and non-POT(power-of-two) numbers, while texture size needs to be the POT numbers. For example, iPhone 4 screen size is 640x960 pixels. Because all textures need to be POT sized, texture size for post-processing should be 1024x1024 to cover all the pixels. But in this case, over half of the pixels are just *wasted*. It really feels bad to me. Because simply wasted amount is huge.

Of course I can use smaller 512x512 texture if the post-processing doesn't need to be pixel-perfect. But still, I waste large portions of memory if I keep aspect-ratio. I can fill the texture by adjusting aspect-ratio, but in this case, we need to adjust fragment shader algorithms to get correct result.

Here're my questions.

1. If I need pixel-perfect post-processing, should I use larger texture which wasting large portion of it? Is this trivial? Or is there better solution? (For example, binding multiple small texture patches to a FBO.)
2. If I use smaller texture, what is trivial method to handle the aspect-ratio issue? Just use only small portion of the texture keeping aspect-ratio? Or adjust the fragment shader algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

After doing some googling around, it appears that OpenGL ES 2 actually does support non-pow2 textures, but not (necessarily) with mipmaps or repeat wrap mode ([source](http://aras-p.info/blog/2012/10/17/non-power-of-two-textures/)).  Fortunately, for postprocessing you don't need mipmaps or repeat wrap mode, so you can size the textures to match the framebuffer exactly.